# Can't run 2 web server with spring-boot-devtools

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I used this [demo](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/),and I added the plugin below to the pom.When I run the server in 8080, I can't use command `mvn spring-boot:run -Dserver.port=9000` to start another server at port 9000. It said I have run a server at 8080.  When read the [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-running-your-application.html), I think the hot swapping is the reason.So I deleted the plugin and it worked well.Why I can't use this plugin to run 2 server at same time?

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that doesn't work is the JVM is forked and the system parameters aren't copied over.  The example from http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/examples/run-debug.html suggests the following:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.jvmArguments="-Dserver.port=9000"
```